# How do I solve "ERROR: missing data for column" with "psql"?

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-copy

I have a makefile in which I am trying to copy the output of a Python program into a table hosted on my PostgreSQL server.

My query looks something like this:

```sh
Python3 filter.py | psql -X -U $(DBUSER) -d $(DBNAME) -h $(DBHOST) -p $(DBPORT) -1 -e \
   -c "COPY table1(col1, col2) FROM STDIN with (format csv, header true, delimiter '|')"
```

However, when I execute it I get the following error message:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "col1"
CONTEXT:  COPY table1, line 168061: ""
```

To try and understand the issue, I exported the output of the Python program to a CSV file and I realized that the issue comes from the fact that there are no more entries after line 168060. So line 168061 is indeed empty.

I have tried using the `NULL` option for `COPY` but it did not work, I get the same error.

I also managed to import into `table1` the content of the physical CSV file using a very similar `COPY` statement. This works, but my objective would be to achieve this without having to create a file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Christian, Try to write a more clear title, something more specific so the people can have a clue before reading the content. By the way, have you tried not sending the empty line at the end?

Comment: Thanks, indeed it was my first post so I will try to be more precise next time :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change `filter.py` so that it doesn't output the offending empty line.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your answers,

Indeed I simply did an easy modification in the filter.py and it works now. I was just too focused on doing it in during the import with PSQL.

Cheers :)